# Finding cycle start and end and calculate frequency from an array

Tags: c#, frequency

This is my very first post so forgive me for making mistakes.

Now what I'm trying to do is calculate frequency from a given double array of readings. This array has corresponding time for each reading.

For instance, readings are like `0.01`, `0.11`, `0.21`, `0.18`, `0.1`, `-0.03`, `-0.2`, `-0.12`, `0` and so on, and each reading has corresponding time in seconds.

The approach I'm using to start and find a cycle is:

```
double start = read[0];
bool trough = false;
double cycle = 0; // Time for one cycle

for (int j = 1; j < read.Count; j++)
{
    if (read[j] < start)
    {
        trough = true;
    }
    else if (trough)
    {
        cycle = seconds[j];
        break;
    }
}
```

This works so far when the cycles are starting nicely from positive reading, but fails when start of cycle is in negative reading.
By cycle i mean a complete sine curve.. so this array of double forms a waveform if plotted in excel with a number of sine curves, like u see on oscilloscopes.. what I'm trying to find is how to efficiently get start and end of one sine wave. In fact start is first value in the array, but how to get the end of first sine wave is where I'm getting lost.
Kindly help, as my brain is completely missing the obvious mistake/solution?
cheers all

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you explain a little more what _defines_ a "cycle" for you and give some more examples which values you want to find from a given array?

Comment: Yes of course, sorry if I'm not very good at explaining.. by cycle i mean a complete sine curve.. so this array of double forms a waveform if plotted in excel with a number of sine curves, like u see on oscilloscopes.. what I'm trying to find is how to efficiently get start and end of one sine wave

Comment: In fact start is first value in the array, but how to get the end of first sine wave is where I'm getting lost

Comment: @shadow2kn Please edit your question to incorporate your comments

Comment: @auburg done, changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sine wave starts at about `0` and is increasing to `0.21` in your example. Then it falls down to `-0.2` and rises to `0` again.

So you first need to find the point where it drops below zero and then detect the moment where it reaches zero again.

You can try it like this:

```
int index = 0;
while (read[index] >= 0) index++; // skip first half sine wave
while (read[index] <= 0) index++; // skip second half
double cycle = seconds[index-1]; // take seconds of the last reading of the wave
```

---

Update: Since your wave can be totally in positive or negative range, we need another approach. Let's try finding

- the first rising part (first 4th of the wave, 0-π/2)
- the falling part (half of the wave, π/2 - 3/2π)
- the last rising part (last 4th of the wave, 3/2π - 2π)

The last one is tricky, because the wave ends when we reached the start value again, not the next maximum.

```
int start = 0; // start of the wave
int index = start + 1; // start at 1 to compare to previous
while (read[index] >= read[index-1]) index++; // skip rising part
index++; // skip the last rising element

while (read[index] =< read[index-1]) index++; // skip falling part
index++;

// now step forward till we reach our start level again
while (read[index] < read[start]) index++; 

// read your time
double cycle = seconds[index-1];

// you can start the next wave here:
start = index; // and do the above in a loop if you need
```

Comment: Thanks alot for that, however this doesn't cater for readings that are all in positive range.. or if all are in negative range.

Comment: @shadow2kn update my answer, hope it helps, am offline now.